# Why is h3.polyfill(geojson, 15) returning empty list for this polygon?

Tags: python, postgis, geojson, h3

I have a polygon the size of an office block in WGS84 coordinate system.

When I run h3.polyfill at resolution 15 it should return a large number of h3 res15 addresses whose centroids are contained in the polygon.

Instead it returns an empty set - why?

I am using h3-3.7.4 with python 3.9.6 on Windows 11.

```
import h3

geojson = {"type":"Polygon",
           "coordinates":[[
               [144.950974,-37.820148],
               [144.95162,-37.819951],
               [144.951856,-37.820324],
               [144.951248,-37.820497],
               [144.950974,-37.820148]
           ]]}

h3_res15_ids = h3.polyfill(geojson, 15)
print(h3_res15_ids)
```

Output:

```
set()
```

I thought maybe the trailing point which equals the first point might be the problem, but removing it does not change the output.

The polygon is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `h3.polyfill_geojson(geojson, 15)` or `h3.polyfill(geojson, 15, geo_json_conformant=True)`

Comment: Awesome thanks.
Wish the documentation was a bit clearer...!